# Two X servers are running

Tags: linux, x11, gnome

I am running to a weird issue. After installation of Suse Enterprise Linux Desktop (this is a custom installation using script), I found that we are running to X servers one on tty7 (default) and one on tty2.

When I dug deep into the issue, the following is observed. The system onstartup runs only one X Server on tty7 with all the related services as user "gdm" on tty7. This I noticed by logging into console in tty1 before logging in at Xconsole in tty7. But immediately after logging in, when i run ps -aef | grep tty2, I found there is an X session started. All the processes were running under the username in which I logged in at tty7. This unnecessarily consumes additional resources.

The desktop is gnome and window manager is xdg

Any hint in what could be going wrong?

Thank you

SKN

Comment: Look at the parent processes (e.g. with `pstree`) to find out which process started the second X server. Then have a very close look at the configuration files related to that process.

Comment: "gdm-session-worker (pam/gdm--password)" -> "gdm-x-session  --run-script gnome"    --> "/usr/bin/X vt2 ...."

Comment: Now look at how this compares to the other X server, and read gdm ("Gnome Display Manager") configuration data until you figure out which parts start one server, and which parts start the other. Assuming you don't have accidentally two gdm's that are running, etc.

Comment: The above is for the second session. The first session starts in vt7 (tty7) which is normal. Not able to understand how logging into the first session starts the second session. I verified in the /etc/gdm/Postlogin /etc/gdm/PostSession /etc/gdm/PreSession but I just have the Default file there. No specific customization is done. the process tree for the second session starts with gdm-session-worker as mentioned above. Any idea what can trigger this process.

Comment: The point was more "see if the first vt7 session has a gdm-session-worker parent with the same PID". Also, while there's plenty of distros that start the X server on vt7, there's also plenty of distros that start the X server on vt2. Possibly your custom installation scripts created a mix. If you can't see anything in the GDM config files, try to adding config files to it (and maybe move the X server to vt4, or change some other detail, so you can see which session it affects). Also look at the systemd config, if you have it.